# addthis button loses functionality in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are trying to use a custom image for addthis functionality along with a carousel tool from here - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/

Everything loads fine and the addthis displays properly initially but if the carousel is advanced the button image loses its functionality.  Here is a demo link.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://ready.listingsmagic.com/slider/

Comment: by "button image" you mean the arrows?

Comment: No I am referring to the blue home icon in the first frame content.

Comment: what function adds that mouseover effect to the blue home icon?

Comment: the addthis javascript api - http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381236-custom-buttons#different-image

Comment: I solved this.  What was happening is that the carousel was cloning the carousel content upon scroll which caused the addthis functionality to break.  There is a toolbox I found - http://www.addthis.com/blog/2013/05/07/a-brief-history-of-using-addthis-dynamically/#.UhPe8T8jGT4 - that explains how to dynamically set/reset the addthis functionality.